# The selector "app-confirm-auto-focus" did not match any elements

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-bootstrap

HI im using Angular 6 with ng-boostrap i added a modal
call FocusComponent and i needed to add it to entryComponents so i added the ConfirmAutoFocusComponent to app.module.ts like so:

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent, ConfirmAutoFocusComponent]
```

it works, but pop me an error on F12 console

```
ERROR Error: The selector "app-confirm-auto-focus" did not match any elements
at DefaultDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.js:1068)
at DebugRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (core.js:11449)
at createElement (core.js:8129)
at createViewNodes (core.js:10360)
at createRootView (core.js:10313)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:10831)
at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:8659)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:3311)
at ApplicationRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.js:4540)
```

i saw other posts about this issue but its dosent seems to work

Comment: Do you have the `<app-confirm-auto-focus>` tag being used directly inside the `index.html` file?

Comment: no i have only the    <app-root></app-root>

Comment: That's why you're getting the error message. If you add it into the `bootstrap` array, you need to include it in the `index.html` so that it can load it as part of the bootstrapping process

Comment: move your ``ConfirmAutoFocusComponent`` from ``bootstrap`` to ``entryComponents : [ConfirmAutoFocusComponent]``

Comment: @CruelEngine :   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [ConfirmAutoFocusComponent] works!

Comment: Add more details and codes

Answer (score 1):

further more  @user184994 and @CruelEngine
added it to app.module.ts as

```
 bootstrap: [AppComponent], entryComponents: [ConfirmAutoFocusComponent]
```

fixed the problem